# QLibrary freezes on call load method

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

There is a big project consisting of several components, presented in the form of dll. In one component I use `QLibrary`, for a call of a code from. Previously, everything worked well, the dll was loaded and everything worked correctly, however, after making a change to the dll code and recompiling it, on one of the launches, when I call the load method, the program just hangs.

I tried to clean the entire project and rebuild it from scratch, but when I call the `boot` method, the execution constantly stops. It does not give any errors. `isLibrary`, called before the load, confirms that the library is selected correctly.

```
void libLoad( QLibrary &lib, const QString &fileName ) {

    lib.setFileName( fileName + dllVersionString );

    auto name = lib.fileName( );    //just to make sure the name is correct
    auto isLibrary = lib.isLibrary( fileName + dllVersionString );  //just to make sure dll is found

    if ((lib).load( )) { //work stops here
        qDebug( ) << QString( "library " + lib.fileName( ) + " loaded" );
    } else {
        throw QString( QString::fromLocal8Bit( "Failed to load library " ) + lib.fileName( ));
    }
}
```

The problem arises only with debug. I use Qt Creator, with msvc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share the relevant parts of your code. Without it we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the breakpoints. I did not understand how they affected the work of the project, but after eliminating all breakpoints and restructuring the component from scratch, the problem went away.

I would be grateful if someone explains the reason for this behavior.